# How to simplfy this indices question Grade 10 :$\frac{3^n-4 \cdot 3^{n-2}}{3^{n+1}-3^{n-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a student in grade 10 and i was given this question about indices 
$$\frac{3^n-4 \cdot 3^{n-2}}{3^{n+1}-3^{n-1}}$$
All I am capable to do is expanding it out, i.e. from $3^{n-2}$ to $3 \cdot 3^{-2}$. I am unable proceed to the next step, please show step by step solution! Thank you!

Comment: Hint : See if you can cancel $3^{n-2}$ from top and bottom.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes sir, sorry bout that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$\frac{3^n-4\cdot 3^n\cdot \frac{1}{9}}{3^n(3-\frac{1}{3})}=\frac{3^n(1-\frac{4}{9})}{3^n(3-\frac{1}{3})}$$

Comment: Sorry Dr., does the $1$ in the $(1-4/9)$ is from $1 * 3^n$

Comment: @Tfue Yes. It is so.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome. You can write:

$3^n-4\times 3^{n-2}=3^n-3^{n-2}-3\times 3^{n-2}$

$3^{n+1}-3^{n-1}=3(3^n-3^{n-2})$

Then the fraction(F) reduces as follows:

$F=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3^{2-n}}\times(\frac{1}{3^{n+1}-3^{n-1}})=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac {5}{24}$

Comment: -1 The second line of math is wrong.

Comment: Servaes thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @sirous thanks mate!